# looping through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to back-test an investment strategy. I am having trouble looping through the DataFrame to "re-create" how the strategy would have done starting 15 years ago.  When I try to loop through the df['Average_Diff'] I keep getting the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64". I've struggled dealing with the nan that would occur in the beginning of the column due to how the values for ['Average_Diff'] were calculated, but once I fixed that I ran into this other problem.  So how can I loop through the df['Average_Diff'] to create the "Buy or Sell" Signal and also loop through to indicate whether I'm in the market or out of the market based on the "Signals"?

```
import pandas as pd 
import pandas.io.data 
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter 
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math
import numpy as np 
from numpy import *
now = datetime.datetime.now()


start_of_interval = datetime.datetime(now.year - 15, now.month, now.day)
end_of_interval = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)       
df = pd.io.data.get_data_yahoo("Spy", start = start_of_interval, end = end_of_interval, interval = "d")['Adj Close']

df = DataFrame(df) 
df['Returns'] = df.pct_change()
df['Average_200'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Adj Close'],200)
df['Average_50'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Adj Close'],50) 
df['Date'] = df.index 

df['Average_Diff'] = df['Average_50'] - df['Average_200']  
df['Average_Diff'] = df['Average_Diff'].fillna(int(2)) 
print(df) 
for i in df['Average_Diff']:
    if df['Average_Diff'][i] == int(2):
    df["Signal"] = "Hold"
    df["Market"] = 1
if df['Average_Diff'][i-1] > 0 and ['Average_Diff'][i] < 0:
    df["Signal"] = "Buy"
    df['Market'] = 1
elif df['Average_Diff'][i-1] < 0 and ['Average_Diff'][i] > 0:
    df["Signal"] = "Sell"
    df["Signal"] = 0 
else:
    df["Signal"] = "Hold" 

for i in df["Market"]:
    if df["Signal"][i] == "Sell":
        df["Market2"] = 0
    elif df['Signal'][i] == "Hold" and df['Market'][i-1] == 0:
        df['Market2'] = 0
    elif df['Signal'][i] == "Hold" and df['Market'][i-1] == 1:  
        df['Market2'] = 1 
    elif df['Signal'][i] == "Buy":
        df['Market2'] = 1 
    else:
        df["Market2"] = 1
```

Comment: You looping looks odd to me. When you do `for i in df['Average_Diff']` you will get the values in the list in df. If there are actual values in there, they are stored as numpy.float64 numbers, not integers. Attempting to use one of those values as an index is what is causing this error.

Comment: Per @LaughingVergil, that loop needs to be revamped. You will want to look at iterators, including `df.iterrows` if you must loop your `dataframes`. But there is little here that couldn't be vectorized /and / or put in a function applied to the `dataframe`.

Comment: Sorry, but both comments are misleading. Modifying values returned by `iterrows()` is a bad idea. Check the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives you can try:

```
l = len(df)
for i in range(len):
    if df.loc[i, 'Average_Diff'] == int(2):
        df.loc[i, 'Signal'] = 'Hold'
        df.loc[i, 'Market'] = 1
```

Or (prefer this, over the one above)

```
for i in df.index.values:
    if df.loc[i, 'Average_Diff'] == int(2):
        df.loc[i, 'Signal'] = 'Hold'
        df.loc[i, 'Market'] = 1
```

**EDIT**

```
l = df.index.values
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    if df.loc[l[i], 'Average_Diff'] == int(2):
        df.loc[l[i], 'Signal'] = 'Hold'
        df.loc[l[i], 'Market'] = 1
    # Even i-1 will work in the same way: l[i-1]
```

---

Contrary to the comments:

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not
>   guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
>   iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
>   effect. [1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows)

Comment: Thank you. This worked for looping through the Dataframe. Although now I have to deal with the issue I'm having for i-1, since it cannot start at i-1. I should be able to solve this one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I didn't realise that the lines below were a part of the loop. Didn't read your code properly till now. Best way then is as I edited...