# looping through the rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file into a dataframe in order to use the fields in a generated sql select statement. The data looks like this:

```
         0    1     2     3     4           5            6
0  status1   A0   NaN   NaN     3   Customer1  customer Id
1  status2   A1   NaN   NaN     3   Customer2  customer Id
2  status3   A2   NaN  1253     3   Customer3  customer Id
3  status4   A3  27.0    L0     12  Customer4  customer Id
4  status5   A3  30.0   NaN     12  Customer5  customer Id
```

and when i loop over each row and try to insert the fields into the string:

```
for row in M:
print("(Select '{}' as disposition, '{}' as category_code, '{}' as status_code, '{:02f}' as Payer_reason_code, {} as precedence, {} as source_id, '{}' as reco_id) union"
          .format(M[row][0], M[row][1], M[row][2], M[row][3], M[row][4], M[row][5], M[row][6]))
```

this error is thrown:

> line 14, in 
>       print("(Select '{}' as disposition, '{}' as category_code, '{}' as status_code, '{:02f}' as Payer_reason_code, {} as precedence, {} as source_id, '{}' as reco_id) union".format(M[row][0], M[row][1], M[row][2], M[row][3], M[row][4], M[row][5], M[row][6]))
>   IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

how do i loop over a numpy 2d array?

here is the full script:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

path = '../resources'

X = pd.read_csv('../resources/data.csv', header=None).as_matrix()

for row in X:
    print("(Select '{}' as disposition, '{}' as category_code, '{}' as status_code, '{:02f}' as Payer_reason_code, {} as precedence, {} as source_id, '{}' as reco_id) union".format(X[row][0], X[row][1], X[row][2], X[row][3], X[row][4], X[row][5], X[row][6]))
```

Comment: this is pandas not numpy.

Comment: if you want numpy, use `X.values`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [looping through a pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958526/looping-through-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Why loop at all? Pandas can append directly into database with one call: [`to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate through a dataframe like that.

```
for i, row in M.iterrows():
    print("(Select '{}' as disposition, '{}' as category_code, '{}' as status_code, '{:02f}' as Payer_reason_code, {} as precedence, {} as source_id, '{}' as reco_id) union"
      .format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]))
```